# Factory with carrierwave upload field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, carrierwave

Hello i need to build up Factory for my model, for example

```
Factory.define :farm do |f|
  f.name { Factory.next :name }
  f.harvest '3'
  f.offers 'Random'
  f.latitude '43'
  f.longitude '-70'
  f.about 'We rocks!'
  f.logo { Factory.next :logo } # this doesn't work
end
```

For now im just pass string "#{n}.jpg" into my logo field and this dont work, how to evalute this field? Im using CarrierWave for uploading.

Comment: https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Use-test-fixtures

Comment: the above wiki page moved to: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Use-test-factories

Answer (score 35):

You need to include `ActionDispatch::TestProcess` in your factory (Rails 3), and use the `fixture_file_upload` helper:

```
include ActionDispatch::TestProcess

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :image do
    title "Example image"
    file { fixture_file_upload("files/example.jpg", "image/jpeg") }
  end
end
```

Also be sure to create an example file at `test/fixtures/files/example.jpg`, otherwise you will get an error that the file does not exist.

Comment: It seems kind of terrible to rely on the existence of an external file during a unit test. Is there anyway to completely stub or encapsulate the file?

Comment: There's nothing terrible about having a test fixture file. As long as you check it into source control it will always be there to run your tests on.

Comment: Yeah terrible is hyperbolic, sorry. Just wanted to know if there was an alternative.

Answer (score 25):

If you don't want to include `ActionDispatch::TestProcess` you can add files like this,

```
Factory.define :brand do |f|
  f.name "My Brand"
  f.description "Foo"
  f.logo { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'support', 'brands', 'logos', 'logo_image.jpg')) }
end
```

Then just include the file at that given path, in this case it would be `spec/support/brands/logos/logo_image.jpg`

This is how they suggest doing it on their wiki https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Use-test-fixtures

Comment: You should use Rack::Test::UploadedFile, because strong parameters won't pass File type.

Comment: Thanks sheerun, I've changed it from `file.open` to use `Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new` instead.